# ARCore plugin for UE4 - repository doesn't exist?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, arcore

I wanted to download arcore plugin for unreal engine 4 but link provided in main page ([link](https://github.com/google-ar-unreal/UnrealEngine.git)) of project settings for unreal doesn't exist. Who knows why? Or this is because of preview version of ARCore? Thanks :)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That repository is actually private. So you cannot access/clone it. What you can do is fork the repository on the link you provided and then clone your fork.

**Edit**
So the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unreal/getting-started) at time of writing is incorrect.
You have to follow the steps to become part of the Epic Organisation on [github](https://unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github). When you follow these steps you'll see a private repos which you need to fork.

TL;DR: The clone command in the guide doesn't work now because the repository is private. Forking it works after become part of Epic organisation @ Github!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is seems that repository is just blank yet or I can't fork it (there is no such button, where it should be). I only can follow this repo :/

Comment: Did you follow all steps to become part of the `Epic Organisation` on Github? I see a private repos which I forked (https://ibb.co/jC0DjF). When you are not part of the organisation you get a 404. Otherwise the repos you seek. Follow these steps: https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to clone it ?

```
git clone -b 4.17-arcore-sdk-preview https://github.com/google-ar-unreal/UnrealEngine.git
```

Comment: Yes, I tried but I get this: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/google-ar-unreal/UnrealEngine.git/' not found